# Check Printer Status in C#

Tags: c#, printing

[image]

I am trying to get a Message if there is no paper in Printer or there is any other error in my Thermal Printer Connected with POS. Can anyone help me how i can get this. I am getting properties as shown below.

```
var server = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue queue = server.DefaultPrintQueue;

//various properties of printQueue
var isOutOfPaper = queue.IsOutOfPaper;
var isOffLine = queue.IsOffline;
var isPaperJam = queue.IsPaperJammed;
var requiresUser = queue.NeedUserIntervention;
var hasPaperProblem = queue.HasPaperProblem;
var isBusy = queue.IsBusy;

if (isOutOfPaper.Equals("true"))
{
  MessageBox.Show(isOutofPaper.ToString());
}
```

I want to show a message using `MessageBox` that Printer is Out of Paper.

See Here it's showing Default Printer Name

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`isOutOfPaper` is a boolean variable. Change your `if` sentence to

```
if (isOutOfPaper)
{
    MessageBox.Show(isOutofPaper.ToString());
}
```

**Remarks**

> If the printer does not support a signal with this meaning, then the property is always false.

---

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isoutofpaper.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `isOutOfPaper.Equals("true")` with `isOutOfPaper`